# Formatting a data.frame: 3 digits after the decimal point

Tags: r, dataframe, format, apply

I have a table which would like to format to 3 digits following the decimal point.

```
    V1 <- c( 0.0727904610967749, 0.004670711, 0.022456166020719)
    V2 <- c( 0.08111, NaN, 0.022222)

 # Method 1
    tab <- data.frame(V1=V1, V2=V2)
    tab2 <- format(tab, digits=3)

# Method 2
    is.num <- sapply(tab2, is.numeric)
    tab2[is.num] <- lapply(tab2[is.num], round, 3)
```

Both give me:

[image]

This is what I expected to see. How can I make this happen?

[image]

Comment: Formatting is not the same as changing the data.  Do you want to preserve the extra digits in the raw data and simply round the values for output or modify the raw data?  If the later, @Cett's solution will work.  If the former, it won't.

Comment: `round(tab, 3)` works for me

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `dplyr`:

```
tab %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ round(.,3))
```

or

```
tab %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ scales::number(., accuracy = 0.001))


#     V1    V2
# 1 0.073 0.081
# 2 0.005  <NA>
# 3 0.022 0.022
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` together with `round`:

```
apply(tab, 2, function(x) round(x, 3))

        V1    V2
[1,] 0.073 0.081
[2,] 0.005   NaN
[3,] 0.022 0.022
```

`apply(tab, 2, f)` applies the function `f` to every column (thats what the `2` represents) of `tab`.